# Does epoll_wait() return events one at a time?

Tags: c, sockets, asynchronous, epoll

Let's say I add a socket an epoll, waiting for both EPOLLIN and EPOLLOUT events, something like this:

```c
struct epoll_event event;
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT;
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, socket, &event);
```

If the socket becomes readable *and* writeable, would I need to call `epoll_wait()` twice to receive both events, or will it return one `epoll_event` with both bitfields set? (Assuming `epoll_wait()` is called with a `maxevents` of 1.)

Comment: Have you considered reading [the documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) for `epoll_wait()`?  If you don't understand the docs then we can clarify, but in that case, please indicate what part you don't understand.

Comment: When I asked the question I had read the man page but was not sure if multiple events were returned as multiple structs or multiple events within one epoll_event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `epoll_wait()` says:

> The *events* field is a bit mask that indicates the events that
> have occurred for the corresponding open file description.

The plural "events" implies that multiple events can occur for the same descriptor.

I believe the `maxevents` argument to `epoll_wait()` actually specifies the maximum elements in the `events` array -- if a single FD has multiple events occur, they're all in one element.

Note that if you use level-triggered events (the default), `EPOLLOUT` will almost always be triggered immediately, since the socket is always ready to write unless you write so much that you fill the kernel's socket buffer.